# Prevent Primary Key increment when an INSERT statement fails in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, auto-increment

I have a simple table in my PostgreSQL database like this:

```
CREATE TABLE person_type
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name character(55) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT person_type_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT person_type_name_key UNIQUE (name)
)
```

As you can see the **id** is automatically incremented and the **name** must be unique. Every time I run an INSERT sql statements, even when it fails, the id is incremented by one.

How can I prevent this? In order that each time a row is inserted successfully, the primary keys are correlative

Comment: You can't prevent. That's the whole point of using sequences. And you don't have to care either. The generated id is just some artificial value that has ***no*** meaning whatsoever. Whether your artificial key is 1, 42, 36387 or 43873483 is completely irrelevant as long as it is unique.

Comment: you could manually set/reset values to sequences, but I doubt it's a good idea.

Comment: Basically a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2036571/398670 . Search for "postgresql gapless sequence" ... and read the manual for `nextval` which discusses this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is exactly what you are facing:

```
test=# CREATE SEQUENCE seq_a;
CREATE SEQUENCE
test=# SELECT nextval('seq_a');
 nextval 
---------
       1
(1 row)

test=# BEGIN;
BEGIN
test=# SELECT nextval('seq_a');
 nextval 
---------
       2
(1 row)

test=# ROLLBACK;
ROLLBACK
test=# SELECT nextval('seq_a');
 nextval 
---------
       3
(1 row)
```

a sequence makes sure that values are ascending BUT it does not make sure that it does not contain gaps. it is also important to notice that a sequence cannot be rollbacked. you cannot have strictly ascending and gap-free at the same time as it would not work with a mix of long and short transactions.
therefore a sequence should never be used for an invoice-id and so on.